# Postgresql allows nonexistent foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-keys, postgresql-12

I have a rails app that uses postgresql 12. Recently, I wrote some tests and saw some strange behavior.
I have a `countries` table. Its schema looks like that:

```
qq2_test=# \d countries;
                                               Table "public.countries"
        Column         |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                Default                
-----------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 id                    | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('countries_id_seq'::regclass)
 domain                | character varying              |           | not null | ''::character varying
 root_city_id          | bigint                         |           |          | 
 language_id           | bigint                         |           | not null | 
 currency_id           | bigint                         |           | not null | 
 google_tag_manager_id | character varying              |           | not null | ''::character varying
 created_at            | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null | 
 updated_at            | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "countries_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_countries_on_domain" UNIQUE, btree (domain)
    "index_countries_on_currency_id" btree (currency_id)
    "index_countries_on_language_id" btree (language_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_6f479b409c" FOREIGN KEY (language_id) REFERENCES languages(id)
    "fk_rails_7cac1212c7" FOREIGN KEY (currency_id) REFERENCES currencies(id)
    "fk_rails_beac36a0bd" FOREIGN KEY (root_city_id) REFERENCES cities(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "country_translations" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_0c4ee35f26" FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "countries_languages" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_556e7398aa" FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "cities" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_996e05be41" FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries(id)
```

As you can see, I have foreign key constraints on both `currency_id` and `language_id` fields.
When I run my tests I see that there are records in that table:

```
qq2_test=# select * from countries;
    id     | domain | root_city_id | language_id | currency_id | google_tag_manager_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         
-----------+--------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
 665664142 | com    |              |  1019186233 |   432072940 |                       | 2020-10-23 06:20:49.288637 | 2020-10-23 06:20:49.288637
 169150333 | by     |              |  1019186233 |   432072940 |                       | 2020-10-23 06:20:49.288637 | 2020-10-23 06:20:49.288637
(2 rows)
```

There are two my test records and they have language and currency references. But their tables are empty:

```
qq2_test=# select * from currencies;
 id | name | symbol | created_at | updated_at 
----+------+--------+------------+------------
(0 rows)

qq2_test=# select * from languages;
 id | name | locale | image | created_at | updated_at 
----+------+--------+-------+------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

Why does postgresql allow nonexistent references in `countries` table?

- Ruby 2.7.1 MRI
- Rails: 6.0.3.4
- Postgresql 12.4
- Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're the only person using the database (since you are talking about small, 1-2 row tests), I would guess that your Rails app (or corresponding driver) is disabling triggers or foreign key checks.  It's totally possible to bypass the foreign key checks like so:

```
edb=# show session_replication_role ;
 session_replication_role 
--------------------------
 origin
(1 row)

edb=# create table city (id int primary key, name text);
CREATE TABLE
edb=# select * from city;
 id | name 
----+------
(0 rows)

edb=# create table person (id int, name text, city int references city(id));
CREATE TABLE
edb=# insert into person values (1,'foo',1);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "person" violates foreign key constraint "person_city_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (city)=(1) is not present in table "city".
edb=# set session_replication_role to replica;
SET
edb=# insert into person values (1,'foo',1);
INSERT 0 1
edb=# select * from person;
 id | name | city 
----+------+------
  1 | foo  |    1
(1 row)

edb=# select * from city;
 id | name 
----+------
(0 rows)
```

I would suggest that you temporarily set `log_statement = all` and run your tests again--then see in your Postgres server logs (default should be `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log` for Ubuntu) what might be disabling your foreign key constraint checks, then address your findings accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for help! Yes, it disables all triggers on all tables. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#fixtures-in-action

Answer (score 2):

There are only two options:

1. The foreign key constraint is `NOT VALID`.

   Such constraints are cheched for new entries, but existing entries can violate them.

   But that would show up in your `\d` output, so that is not the case.
2. You have data corruption.

   Apart from hardware problems or software bugs, possible explanations are:

   - Someone set `session_replication_role = replica` so that triggers don't fire.
   - A superuser ran

     ```
     ALTER TABLE countries DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
     ```

Comment: Thanks so much for help. Indeed, rails tests do series of 'disable trigger - insert - enable trigger' queries. Also I found explanation in rails docs https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#fixtures-in-action